# devexpress xtratreelist poor performance

Tags: performance, xtratreelist

I have a simple xtratreelist on a form and I have a simple firebird data table with 846 rows. I select 5 columns from the database and I populate the treelist.

Here is the code:

```
ConnectToDb(fbconn, CEGNEV)
    fbcommand.Connection = fbconn
    fbcommand.CommandText = "select szamlaszam, szamlanev, szamlacsop, szamlatip, szamlakat from szamlatukor order by szamlaszam"
    fbadapter.SelectCommand = fbcommand
    fbadapter.Fill(fbdataset)
    fbdataset.Tables(0).TableName = "szamlatukor"
    trlSzamlatukor.DataMember = "szamlatukor"
    trlSzamlatukor.DataSource = fbdataset
    trlSzamlatukor.ParentFieldName = "szamlaszam"
    trlSzamlatukor.PopulateColumns()
    fbconn.Close()
```

Populating the treelist takes 18 seconds! This is slow, very slow.

I added a xtragridcontrol too and populate this with the same table. It happens in a time of a mouseclick.

What could be the reason for the poor performance of the treelist?

Comment: Was the answer below helpfull? Have you made any progress, what have you tried? Could you pinpoint the source of the slow population?
I assume it would help your reputation if you would be polite enough to reply if someone has tried to help you.

Answer (score 2):

What is about trying this, which avoids immediate visual updates?

```
trlSzamlatukor.BeginUpdate()
trlSzamlatukor.PopulateColumns()
trlSzamlatukor.EndUpdate()
```

Comment: Because I have given this answer: Meanwhile I learned that BeginUpdate does not have any effect on PopulateColumns().
When I do some simple measurements, I can recognize that PopulateColumns() for the XtraTreeList has kind of an O(n*n) dependency in the number of items.
However, it's much better than 18s for only 845 items, e.g. about 800ms for 10000 items (and then already 13500ms for 40000 items).
But I did not use a dataset, only a datatable. 

1) Using DataTable.Rows.Add
2) Using a real table in SQL Server Express.

There are almost the same results.